# AsyncTask wont change the values of other variables

Tags: java, android, multithreading, jdbc, android-asynctask

i am making an android app that uses jdbc to connect to a database, jdbc needs AsyncTask, i read a tutorial about it but, i have all kinds of troubles !

code :

```
// login stuff
Button Login;
EditText Username, Password;
String db_username, db_password;

// database variables
Database d;
ResultSet rs;
Statement stmt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    getActionBar().hide();

    // defining stuff
    Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    db_password = "-1";

    // focus on the enter username
    Username.requestFocus();

    Login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // checking for the password and stuff
            Con deploy = new Con();
            deploy.execute();
            // waiting until data is back
            while (db_password.equals("-1")){   
            }
            // checking the entered password
            if (db_password.equals(Password.getText())) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Manager.class);
                i.putExtra("name", db_username);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }

    });

}

// connection class
private class Con extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        d = new Database();
        d.connect();

        try {

            // putting the username and pass in the result set
            stmt = d.createStatement();
            rs = stmt
                    .executeQuery("SELECT username,password from users WHERE username='"
                            + Username.getText() + "'");

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        try {
            if (rs.next()) {
                db_username = rs.getString("username");
                db_password = rs.getString("password");
                System.out.println("check point");
                System.out.println(db_password);
                db_password = "0";

            } else {

                Username.setText("");
                Password.setText("");
                db_password = "0";
            }
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }


}
```

after testing i figured, inside the thread the value changes as in the database, but on the main thread the two variables db_username db_password never changes !
i made these variables static but didnt work , please help

---

Solved : i used this instead of AcyncTask and solved everything:

```
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {


            }).start();
```

Comment: What about making them `volatile`?

Comment: It's probably also worth pointing out that it somewhat defeats the point of an asynchronous task if you block until it completes. Why not try defining a callback method in the outer class which the `AsyncTask` calls when it finishes, rather than waiting for the variable to change?

Comment: really? Sir?.. return your values to your onpostexecute code

Comment: that while you are doing is a bit dangerous. If there is any error in the database or getting the results, that while never stops and the UI just freezes. Remove it and call a method that has the startActivity from onPostExecute and just call the async task from the click listener method of the button. Also don't just catch the exception and not print anything, even a error message. Put something there so you can make sure that there was no error querying the database.

Comment: Sir, if it helped let okay? or let me know whats up

Comment: @Elltz thank you sir,, your feedback really helped, sorry still a new user

Comment: okay, Sir, but i want to know if using the async task was able to change the values using my approach? did the print out print the new value or the old value?

Answer (score -1):

```
private class Con extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ResultSet > {

@Override
protected ResultSet doInBackground(Void... params) {

    d = new Database();
    d.connect();
    ResultSet  rs;
    try {

        // putting the username and pass in the result set
        Statement stmt = d.createStatement();
        rs = stmt
                .executeQuery("SELECT username,password from users WHERE username='"
                        + Username.getText() + "'");

    } catch (Exception e) {
       return new ResultSet(); // depends on what you want to do on error 
    }

    return rs;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ResultSet result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    try {
        if (result.next()) {
            db_username = result.getString("username");
            db_password = result.getString("password");
            System.out.println("check point");
            System.out.println(db_password);
           // db_password = "0"; this always makes it zero at the end of the day

        } else {

            Username.setText("");
            Password.setText("");
            db_password = "0";
        }
    } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**Edit** also change this `if (db_password.equals(Password.getText().toString())) {` its in your onclick listener

use this asnyc ayt.. check closing tags and stuff..

Comment: why would this fix the issue? It is better to do it like this, but I don't see how it can possibly fix his issue.

Comment: i dont know why but it doesnt change the value of the variables above, is there anything else i can use instead of AsyncTask ?

Comment: @AbdullahAsendar do the `System.out.println(db_password);` print out the new value? if so, then your asnyc task checks out good so move on to your comparing of  strings, ok?.. check the edited answer on that too.. (that's if the first statement is true)

Comment: @androidpotato7 _why?_ well, pay attention to it Sir, _but I don't see how it can possibly fix his issue_  you have to wait and see..

Comment: ok all was good, and i managed to solve the problem, BUT comparing the two strings Password.getText().equals(db_password); always returns false , tried to print the two variables in the console, they are the same, but still returns false, then i put the on click listener in the AsyncTask class but it doesnt start the other activity,, i am using the AsyncTask for the first time so maybe i am doing something wrong, thank you so much @Elltz

Comment: yeah use this `Password.getText().toString()` instead of `Password.getText()` and it will return true if they are the same..@AbdullahAsendar , and no don't put it in the async task, let it be in the first instance is great..